# Prove that the sequence $a_n = \int_1^2 \sqrt[n]{{e}^{x^2}}\, dx$ converge

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

I have the following sequence:
$$a_n = \int_1^2 \sqrt[n]{{e}^{x^2}}\, dx$$

My aim is to prove that ${\{a_n\}^\infty_2}$ converges.

My idea was simply showing that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_1^2 \sqrt[n]{{e}^{x^2}}\, dx$ equals $\int_1^2 {e}^{{\frac{x^2}{\infty}}}\, dx$ and therefore equals $\int_1^2 {1}\, dx$ which equals $2-1$ (in other words, showing that the limit exists and is a finite number)

Is that enough to show that the sequence converges? or must i use epsilon defintion in order to do that?

Comment: It's a sequence that is clearly bounded below by zero. Have you considered trying to prove that this is a monotone decreasing sequence? (it can be seen graphically), then by it's boundedness, this then implies it is convergent.

Comment: *Hint.* $e^{1/n} \leq e^{x^2/n} \leq e^{4/n}$ on $x\in[1,2]$. How would this improve to a bound on $a_n$?

Comment: Both of you methods are great, but i mainly try to understand whether showing the limit like i did is an acceptable way of proving this..

Comment: @Limitless You can use what you did as a way of figuring out what the limit should be, but then you need to use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition to actually prove it.

Comment: @Limitless whether you need $\epsilon - \delta$ depends heavily on what this is actually for; most people would use bounded convergence theorem (you kind of plugged in the limit inside the integral, which is not OK; you actually need to make sure the integrand satisfies one of few properties (and being bounded is one of them)) and then pretty much argue what you did; for an intro analysis class, you might be expected to go through an epsilon-delta argument.

Comment: Interchanging two limit operators (in this case, limit and integral) may change the value (or even the convergence) of the expression in general. Now given that this does not come free, you need to either build a criterion which guarantees this type of manipulation or devise a workaround solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_n(x) = e^{x^2/n}$ for $x \in [1,2]$.  As OP observes, $f_n \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} 1$ pointwisely.

$f_n$ is monotone and continuous on a closed and bounded interval $[1,2]$, so by [Dini's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem), we can upgrade the pointwise convergence to uniform convergence, which allows interchanging of integral and limit signs.

As a result, $a_n \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} \int_1^2 1 = 1$.

Comment: With the argument you use one can conclude that $x^n$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$, or am I missing something?

Comment: The mentioned conditions are not enough as Shashi pointed out. In this case, the fact that $f_n$ monotone-decreases to $1$ allows us to invoke Dini’s theorem to improve pointwise convergence to uniform convergence. Of course, a direct estimate $\| f_n-1\| = e^{4/n}-1$ is also enough for uniform convergence.

Comment: @Shashi I'll fix my answer.

Comment: @SangchulLee  Thanks for your comment.